# Memory Leak Issue. Eye-tracking in Unity with OpenCVSharp

Tags: c#, opencv, unity-game-engine, memory-leaks

I've been working on this project for a few months now, where I'm trying to integrate eye-tracking into Unity using OpenCVSharp. I've managed to get everything working, including the actual tracking of the pupil etc, however I've got a memory leak. Basically after 20-30seconds of the program running it freezes and the console errors saying "Unable to allocate (insert number here) bits". After looking at the memory usage during running of the program, you can see its use steadily climb until it maxes then crashes.

Now I've spent quite a while trying to fix the issue, and read a lot of help posts about releasing images/storage etc correctly. Despite the fact I'm doing this, it doesn't appear to be releasing them correctly. I tried using the garbage collector to force it to reclaim the memory however that didn't seem to work either. Am I just doing something fundamentally wrong with the images and how I reclaim them? Or is having the creation of new images each frame (even though I'm releasing them) causing the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's the code below, you can ignore a lot of the stuff within the update function as its to do with the actual tracking section and calibration. I realise the code is pretty messy, sorry about that! The main section to worry about is EyeDetection().

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.IO;
using OpenCvSharp;
using OpenCvSharp.Blob;
//using System.Xml;
//using System.Threading;
//using AForge;

//using OpenCvSharp.Extensions;
//using System.Windows.Media;
//using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;



public class CaptureScript2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    //public GameObject planeObj;
    public WebCamTexture webcamTexture;     //Texture retrieved from the webcam
    //public Texture2D texImage;              //Texture to apply to plane
    public string deviceName;

    private int devId = 1;
    private int imWidth = 800;             //camera width
    private int imHeight = 600;             //camera height
    private string errorMsg = "No errors found!";
    private static IplImage camImage;                   //Ipl image of the converted webcam texture
    //private static IplImage yuv;
    //private static IplImage dst;
    private CvCapture cap;                  //Current camera capture
    //private IplImage eyeLeft;
    //private IplImage eyeRight;
    //private IplImage eyeLeftFinal;
    //private IplImage eyeRightFinal;
    private double leftEyeX;
    private double leftEyeY;
    private double rightEyeX;
    private double rightEyeY;
    private int calibState;
    private double LTRCPx;
    private double LTLCPx;
    private double LBLCPy;
    private double LTLCPy;
    private double RTRCPx;
    private double RTLCPx;
    private double RBLCPy;
    private double RTLCPy;
    private double gazeWidth;
    private double gazeHeight;
    private double gazeScaleX;
    private double gazeScaleY;

    public static CvMemStorage storageFace;
    public static CvMemStorage storage;

    public static double gazePosX;
    public static double gazePosY;

    private bool printed = true;
    //private CvRect r;
    //private IplImage smallImg;

    CvColor[] colors = new CvColor[]
    {
        new CvColor(0,0,255),
        new CvColor(0,128,255),
        new CvColor(0,255,255),
        new CvColor(0,255,0),
        new CvColor(255,128,0),
        new CvColor(255,255,0),
        new CvColor(255,0,0),
        new CvColor(255,0,255),
    };

    //scale for small image
    const double Scale = 1.25;
    const double scaleEye = 10.0;
    const double ScaleFactor = 2.5;
    //must show 2 eyes on the screen
    const int MinNeighbors = 2;
    const int MinNeighborsFace = 1;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {


        //Webcam initialisation
        WebCamDevice[] devices = WebCamTexture.devices;
        Debug.Log ("num:" + devices.Length);

        for (int i=0; i<devices.Length; i++) 
        {
            print (devices [i].name);
            if (devices [i].name.CompareTo (deviceName) == 1) 
            {
                devId = i;
            }
        }

        if (devId >= 0) 
        {
            //mainImage = new IplImage (imWidth, imHeight, BitDepth.U8, 3);


        }

        //create capture from current device
        cap = Cv.CreateCameraCapture(devId);
        //set properties of the capture
        Cv.SetCaptureProperty(cap, CaptureProperty.FrameWidth, imWidth);
        Cv.SetCaptureProperty(cap, CaptureProperty.FrameHeight, imHeight);
        //create window to display capture
        //Cv.NamedWindow("Eye tracking", WindowMode.AutoSize);
        Cv.NamedWindow ("EyeLeft", WindowMode.AutoSize);
        Cv.NamedWindow ("EyeRight", WindowMode.AutoSize);
        Cv.NamedWindow ("Face", WindowMode.AutoSize);

        calibState = 1;


    }


    void Update ()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && calibState < 3)
        {
            calibState++;
        }

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && calibState < 4)
        {
            printed = false;
            calibState++;

            Cv.DestroyAllWindows();
            Cv.ReleaseCapture(cap);

            cap = Cv.CreateCameraCapture(devId);
        }
        //if device is connected
        if (devId >= 0)
        {   
            //cap = Cv.CreateCameraCapture(devId);
            //Cv.Release
            //retrieve the current frame from camera
            camImage = Cv.QueryFrame(cap);
            //detect eyes and apply circles
            //
            EyeDetection();

            Cv.ReleaseImage(camImage);
            //PupilTracking();



            switch(calibState)
            {
            case 1:
                LTRCPx = leftEyeX;
                RTRCPx = rightEyeX;

                break;

            case 2:

                LTLCPx = leftEyeX;
                LTLCPy = leftEyeY;
                RTLCPx = rightEyeX;
                RTLCPy = rightEyeY;

                break;
            case 3:

                LBLCPy = leftEyeY;// + rightEyeY) /2 ;
                RBLCPy = rightEyeY;


                break;

            case 4:

                //gazeWidth = (((LTRCPx - LTLCPx) + (RTRCPx - RTLCPx)) / 2) * -1;
                //gazeHeight = ((LBLCPy - LTLCPy) + (RBLCPy - RTLCPy)) /2;
                gazeWidth = LTLCPx -LTRCPx;
                gazeHeight = LBLCPy - LTLCPy;

                gazeScaleX = (Screen.width/gazeWidth);
                gazeScaleY = Screen.height/gazeHeight;

                gazePosX = gazeScaleX *(leftEyeX - LTRCPx);
                gazePosY = gazeScaleY *(leftEyeY - LTLCPy);

                break;
            }


            //Cv.ReleaseCapture(cap);

        } 
        else 
        {
            Debug.Log ("Can't find camera!");
        }

        //print (calibState);
        if(printed == false)
        {
            print ("Gaze pos x = " + gazePosX);
            print ("Gaze pos Y = " + gazePosY);
            print ("Scale x = " + gazeScaleX);
            print ("Scale y = " + gazeScaleY);
            print ("Gaze width = " + gazeWidth);
            print ("Gaze Height = " + gazeHeight);
            print ("left eye x = " + leftEyeX);
            print ("left eye Y = " + leftEyeY);
            print ("calib state = " + calibState);

            printed = true;
        }



        //Cv.ShowImage("Eye tracking", mainImage);
        //Cv.ShowImage ("EyeLeft", grayEyeLeft);
        //Cv.ShowImage ("EyeRight", grayEyeRight);

    }



    void EyeDetection()
    {
        IplImage mainImage = new IplImage (imWidth, imHeight, BitDepth.U8, 3);

        IplImage smallImg = new IplImage(mainImage.Width, mainImage.Height ,BitDepth.U8, 1);
        Cv.Resize (camImage, mainImage, Interpolation.Linear);

        IplImage gray = new IplImage(mainImage.Size, BitDepth.U8, 1);

        Cv.CvtColor (mainImage, gray, ColorConversion.BgrToGray);
        Cv.Resize(gray, smallImg, Interpolation.Linear);
        Cv.EqualizeHist(smallImg, smallImg);
        Cv.ReleaseImage (gray);


            //IplImage hack = Cv.LoadImage("\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Honours Projects\\Project10\\Project\\Assets\\bug.jpeg");
            //Cv.Erode (hack, hack);
            //Cv.ReleaseImage (hack);

            //uint sizeStore = 2877212;
        CvHaarClassifierCascade cascadeFace = CvHaarClassifierCascade.FromFile("\\Users\\User\\Documents\\opencv\\sources\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml");

        CvMemStorage storageFace = new CvMemStorage();
        storageFace.Clear ();

        CvSeq<CvAvgComp> faces = Cv.HaarDetectObjects(smallImg, cascadeFace, storageFace, ScaleFactor, MinNeighborsFace, 0, new CvSize(30,30));

        for(int j = 0; j < faces.Total; j++)
        {
            CvRect face = faces[j].Value.Rect;

            CvHaarClassifierCascade cascadeEye = CvHaarClassifierCascade.FromFile ("\\Users\\User\\Documents\\opencv\\sources\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_eye.xml");

            IplImage faceImg = new IplImage(face.Width, face.Height, BitDepth.U8, 1);
            IplImage faceImgColour = new IplImage(face.Width, face.Height, BitDepth.U8, 3);

            CvMemStorage storage = new CvMemStorage();
            storage.Clear ();

            Cv.SetImageROI(smallImg, face);
            Cv.Copy (smallImg, faceImg);
            Cv.ResetImageROI(smallImg);

            Cv.SetImageROI(mainImage, face);
            Cv.Copy (mainImage, faceImgColour);
            Cv.ResetImageROI(mainImage);


            Cv.ShowImage ("Face", faceImgColour);


            CvSeq<CvAvgComp> eyes = Cv.HaarDetectObjects(faceImg, cascadeEye, storage, ScaleFactor, MinNeighbors, 0, new CvSize(30, 30));
            for(int i = 0; i < eyes.Total; i++)
            {
                CvRect r = eyes[i].Value.Rect;


                Cv.SetImageROI(faceImgColour, r);

                if(i == 1)
                {
                    IplImage eyeLeft = new IplImage(new CvSize(r.Width, r.Height), BitDepth.U8, 3);

                    Cv.Copy(faceImgColour, eyeLeft);

                    IplImage yuv = new IplImage(eyeLeft.Size, BitDepth.U8, 3);
                    IplImage dst = new IplImage(eyeLeft.Size, BitDepth.U8, 3);
                    IplImage grayEyeLeft = new IplImage(eyeLeft.Size, BitDepth.U8, 1);
                    IplImage eyeLeftFinal = new IplImage(Cv.Round(grayEyeLeft.Width * scaleEye), Cv.Round(grayEyeLeft.Height * scaleEye), BitDepth.U8, 1);
                    Cv.CvtColor(eyeLeft, yuv, ColorConversion.BgrToCrCb);
                    Cv.Not(yuv, dst);
                    Cv.CvtColor(dst,eyeLeft,ColorConversion.CrCbToBgr);
                    Cv.CvtColor(eyeLeft, grayEyeLeft, ColorConversion.BgrToGray);

                    Cv.Resize (grayEyeLeft, eyeLeftFinal, Interpolation.Linear);
                    Cv.Threshold(eyeLeftFinal, eyeLeftFinal, 230, 230, ThresholdType.Binary);
                    CvBlobs b1 = new CvBlobs(eyeLeftFinal);
                    if(b1.Count > 0)
                    {
                        leftEyeX = b1.LargestBlob().Centroid.X;
                        leftEyeY = b1.LargestBlob().Centroid.Y;
                    }

                    Cv.ShowImage ("EyeLeft", eyeLeftFinal);

                    Cv.ReleaseImage (yuv);
                    Cv.ReleaseImage (dst);
                    Cv.ReleaseImage (grayEyeLeft);
                    Cv.ReleaseImage (eyeLeftFinal);
                    b1.Clear();

                    Cv.ReleaseImage (eyeLeft);


                }
                if(i == 0)
                {
                    IplImage eyeRight = new IplImage(new CvSize(r.Width, r.Height), BitDepth.U8, 3);

                    Cv.Copy(faceImgColour, eyeRight);

                    IplImage yuv2 = new IplImage(eyeRight.Size, BitDepth.U8, 3);
                    IplImage dst2 = new IplImage(eyeRight.Size, BitDepth.U8, 3);
                    IplImage grayEyeRight = new IplImage(eyeRight.Size, BitDepth.U8, 1);
                    IplImage eyeRightFinal = new IplImage(Cv.Round(grayEyeRight.Width * scaleEye), Cv.Round(grayEyeRight.Height * scaleEye), BitDepth.U8, 1);
                    Cv.CvtColor(eyeRight, yuv2, ColorConversion.BgrToCrCb);
                    Cv.Not(yuv2, dst2);
                    Cv.CvtColor(dst2,eyeRight,ColorConversion.CrCbToBgr);
                    Cv.CvtColor(eyeRight, grayEyeRight, ColorConversion.BgrToGray);

                    Cv.Resize (grayEyeRight, eyeRightFinal, Interpolation.Linear);
                    Cv.Threshold(eyeRightFinal, eyeRightFinal, 230, 230, ThresholdType.Binary);
                    CvBlobs b2 = new CvBlobs(eyeRightFinal);

                    if(b2.Count > 0)
                    {
                        rightEyeX = b2.LargestBlob().Centroid.X;
                        rightEyeY = b2.LargestBlob().Centroid.Y;
                    }

                    Cv.ShowImage ("EyeRight", eyeRightFinal);

                    Cv.ReleaseImage (yuv2);
                    Cv.ReleaseImage (dst2);
                    Cv.ReleaseImage (grayEyeRight);
                    Cv.ReleaseImage (eyeRightFinal);
                    b2.Clear ();

                    Cv.ReleaseImage (eyeRight);

                }

                Cv.ResetImageROI(faceImgColour);
            }

            //Cv.ShowImage("Eye tracking", mainImage);

            Cv.ReleaseImage (faceImg);
            Cv.ReleaseImage (faceImgColour);
            Cv.ReleaseMemStorage(storage);
            Cv.ReleaseHaarClassifierCascade(cascadeEye);


        }

        Cv.ReleaseMemStorage(storageFace);
        Cv.ReleaseHaarClassifierCascade(cascadeFace);


        //PupilTracking ();
        Cv.ReleaseImage(smallImg);
        Cv.ReleaseImage (mainImage);
        GC.Collect();

    }

    void OnGUI ()
    {
            GUI.Label (new Rect (200, 200, 100, 90), errorMsg);
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        Cv.DestroyAllWindows();
        Cv.ReleaseCapture(cap);
    }
```

Comment: So you're saying that there is, as far as you're aware, no solution to the issue, and its just a problem with using OpenCVSharp?

Comment: This blog has a nice section on memory optimization: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2015/02/05/unity-tips-1

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with OpenCV, but as a general rule:

- I would **limit instantiation** in the Update loop, like `new CvMemStorage()`
- **Don't load data in the Update loop**: `CvHaarClassifierCascade.FromFile("\\Users\\User\\Documents\\opencv\\sources\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml");` That should be loaded once on start and assigned to a class variable.
- **Allocate on start and Release only if needed**.

I find that in most situations there's plenty of RAM to go around. I allocate on `Start()` what is going to be used over and over, especially 60 times per second in the `Update()` loop!

But Loading XML data, Allocating and releasing variables like `storage` or `cascadeEye`, is bound to create issues when the app is trying to do so 60 times a second.

**Creating and destroying objects is a very, very, very expensive.** So do so wisely and sparingly, especially when dealing with complex data structures like the OpenCV objects, bitmaps or loaders.

hth.